# Request hitting varnish and getting served and not checking mod_security rule?

Tags: linux, varnish, httpd.conf, varnish-vcl, mod-security

I have a reverse proxy server on which mod_security is configured to be used as web application firewall and varnish is for cache. I have blocked a country but as request hit Varnish and getting served. The setup is like below

Request > Varnish[80] > Mod_security/HTTPD[8080]

On opening page on 8080, the rule is working , but on 80 the request is getting served by the Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your geolocation rules into varnish for it to get use of varnish (alternatives are really bad for cache hitrates). Theres a VMOD for geo-location called https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-geoip